# Detect and Add dynamically width and height and alt attribute to all images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get and add dynamically the width, height and alt attribute for each image on the web page that doesn't have those attributes. But it only detects the first image width height alt attributes and adds them too all images.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $('img').width();
    var height = $('img').height();
    var image_width = $('img').attr('width');
    var image_height = $('img').attr('height');
    var image_alt = $('img').attr('alt');
    if (typeof image_width === 'undefined' || image_width === false && typeof image_height === 'undefined' || image_height === false) {
        $('img').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
    }
    if (typeof image_alt === 'undefined' || image_alt === false) {
        $('img').attr('alt', 'image');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9zsqxov/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your img tags and perform your logic on each. "$('img').width()" only returns the value for the first image it finds (as you found out).

For example:

```
$('img').each(function() {
  var $img = $(this),
      width = $img.width(),

  // ..the rest of your logic here..
});
```

Comment: one more thing could you help me convert it to javascript? I know it's similar but don't get it how.

Comment: From Jquery to Javascipt.

Comment: Selecting elements by tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName. Getting width/height, see offsetHeight|Width: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp. Getting element attributes: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is OK but you have to loop through all the `img` elements, not just the first one. Here's a simple example:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').each(function() {
            var width = $(this).width();
            var height = $(this).height();
            $(this).attr('width', width);
            $(this).attr('height', height);
        });
    });
```